# Java - can I reflectively find out if I'm being called from a function within a catch block for a partifuclar exception?

Tags: java, reflection

First of all, I want to make something clear before I get yelled at: I have no plans to write any code that will ever use this sort of control flow; its obviously terrible. Forget about a use case, this is more a question about whether its possible or not:

I want to know if its possible to know if somewhere up the call stack, a function is being called within a catch block for a particular exception.

Let's say I have a function:

```
foo() {
try {
    something
}
catch (SuperException s) {
    bar()
}
```

So given NO control over the method signature of bar, and given bar is also called by many other functions, can bar behave differently if called in catch block catching a superexception? (and no, being called by foo isn't a sufficient condition, its the super exception that matters)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look at the call stack and get the line numbers of each call.

You can read the byte code to determine where the catch blocks are and which lines of code are in those blocks.

Match the two together to see if anywhere in the call stack is in a catch block.

Note: this will only work if you have debug information compiled in your code.